# How can I install SCISOFT 8 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install scisoft 8 on Ubuntu 18.04, and from where can I get the tar file of scisoft 8 to be downloaded? I have followed [the instructions in this blog](http://navtejblog.blogspot.com/2014/05/installing-eso-scisoft-on-ubuntu-1404.html) to download scisoft 7.7 on Ubuntu 14.14, but I get this problem on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
USER@~$ libsdl-image1.2:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 unixodbc:i386
libsdl-image1.2:i386: command not found
(base) user@user:~$ sudo dpkg -i libg2c0_3.4.6-8ubuntu2_i386.deb 
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'libg2c0_3.4.6-8ubuntu2_i386.deb': No such file or directory
(base) user@user:~$ sudo dpkg -i gcc-3.4-base_3.4.6-8ubuntu2_i386.deb
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'gcc-3.4-base_3.4.6-8ubuntu2_i386.deb': No such file or directory
```

Comment: You are using package names as sommands.
The instructions in the blog are relatively clear (though I cannot confirm the work).

What I think that is happening here is that you confuse a command that is one line, for two commands.  The blog states:

`sudo apt-get install tcsh:i386 libgfortran3:i386 libreadline5:i386 
libsdl-image1.2:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 unixodbc:i386`

That is one line, even though the command is wrapped to two in the blog.
The command line command here is `sudo apt-get`, with the command `install` for that command, then with a list of packages.

Answer (score 0):

There are some instructions to install Scisoft on Ubuntu [here on the University of Istanbul's website](http://cosmology.istanbul.edu.tr/index.php/members/installation-of-scisoft/), which are similar to the instructions you found:

> **Installation of SCISOFT into an Ubuntu:**
>
> Download [scisoft.tar](http://cosmology.istanbul.edu.tr/korhan/scisoft.tar) [this is a direct link - clicking will start the download or prompt for confirmation to download] to your `/` directory

Then it gives these commands:

> ```
> cd /
> sudo tar xvzf scisoft.tar
> sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
> sudo apt-get install tcsh:i386 libgfortran3:i386 libreadline5:i386
> sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386
> sudo apt-get install unixodbc:i386 libxft2:i386 libxrandr2:i386
> sudo apt-get install libxmu6:i386 libxss1:i386
> echo ". /scisoft/bin/Setup.bash" >> ~/.bash_profile
> source ~/.bash_profile
> run ecl…done
> ```
>
> if necessary:
>
> sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386 lib32stdc++6 lib64stdc++6 libxft2:i386

But these instructions seem unlikely to work on Ubuntu 18.04. The page does not say when they were updated, but it seems they are for an earlier version, because some of the library versions are old. For example, the instructions ask for `libgfortran3`, but Ubuntu 18.04 repositories have `libgfortran5`. Perhaps the software will run with the newer version of the libraries, but perhaps it will crash. Downgrading the libraries could horribly break other things on your system, so don't do that.

If you want to try following these instructions, I would first suggest not downloading the tarball to `/`, but instead to a local directory or to `/tmp` so that you can untar it without `sudo` and limit the cleanup you have to do if the installation doesn't go well. After downloading the file, go to the location where it downloaded to, which you can see in your browser when you download it, or in your browser preferences. In a terminal, to change directory, you use the `cd` command, for example one of these might work:

```
cd Downloads
cd /tmp/mozilla_$USER0
```

Check that the file is in the current directory using the `ls` command. If you see the scisoft file there you can run the tar command (without `sudo`)

```
tar xvzf scisoft.tar
```

And then you can try installing the dependencies. I recommend doing this one by one so that you can solve any problems that occur. If you don't have any 32-bit software on your system already, you may need to run

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

and then

```
sudo apt install libc6:i386
```

and so on for all the packages in the instructions.

If you get an error saying that no package was found, you can use `apt search` or https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to try to find the equivalent package for your version of Ubuntu.

---

According to the [this page on the ESO website](http://www.eso.org/sci/software/scisoft/), Scisoft is packaged for Fedora, CentOS and Scientific Linux, so you can probably save yourself a lot of trouble by installing one of those distributions instead of, alongside, or perhaps in a virtual machine inside, your Ubuntu 18.04 system.

Comment: @Zanna - hi there, yes you right, i did not test the commands on my ubuntu first, and it is my fault, i was just trying to help and i learned for the next time to post an answer just for a double checked answer, any way i was really wanted to help and i did not want to make any damage.

Comment: Of course I realise that you were trying to help. The instructions from the University of Istanbul website are actually pretty much the same as [the instructions OP was following](http://navtejblog.blogspot.com/2014/05/installing-eso-scisoft-on-ubuntu-1404.html) and seem contemporary - that is, they are unlikely to work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @VivekSharma see updated post - but I am not optimistic that these instructions will work. Also the file is huge.

Comment: it doesn't work on ubuntu 18 , please first check it on terminal your own then then send valid command

Comment: @VivekSharma problem is the tarball is huge - firefox says it's going to take 3 hours to download - and I'm on 20.04 anyway. If you get started on it and have issues I'd be happy to try to help you overcome each step that causes problems, but my recommendation is to install Fedora or CentOS or Scientific Linux in dual boot or a virtual machine (or instead of Ubuntu) to use this software.